# What is the JavaScript variable scope in a switch / case statement?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, scope

While creating JavaScript with ASP.NET MVC I noticed several scope warnings and realized that I am missing something with understanding the variable scope inside the switch / case statement.

**Warning: 'i' is already defined** referring to case b and case c

My code looks similar to this:

```
switch(element) {
  case 'a':
   for(var i=0; i < count; i++){
    do something
   }
   break;

  case 'b':
   for(var i=0; i < count; i++){
    do something
   }
   break;

  case 'c':
   for(var i=0; i < count; i++){
    do something
   }
   break;
}
```

I thought scope ended with each break statement but it seems that scope does not end until the end of the switch/case. Is scope for the entire switch/case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#lexical_scoping): *"The `case` and `default` clauses don't create lexical scopes."*

Therefore, all variables declared inside a `switch` statement, live within the same scope. Declaring a variable using `let/const` with the same name with throw an Error.

```
switch(someVar) {
    case 1:
        let a;
        break;
    case 2:
        let a; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
        break;
}
```

If you want to create a separate (nested) block scope inside a `case` clause, you can use `labels`:

```
switch(someVar) {
    case 1: { // <- creates a new block scope
        let a;
        break;
    }
    case 2: { // <- creates a new block scope
        let a; 
        break;
    }
}
```

There is no C-like language (that I know of) in which each `case` statement forms an independent scope.

For example, the following C# code will also not compile:

```
switch(someVar) {
    case 1:
        int a;
        break;
    case 2:
        int a;        // 'a' is already defined
        break;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I must be falling asleep on this one because at first glance it seemed right. But joy for compiler warnings to let me know when I've fallen asleep. Thank You for such a great answer.

Comment: Note that in C-like languages (not Javascript) you can create a scope yourself after the case if you wish to:  `case 1: { ... }`

Comment: FYI, nowadays ES6 syntax allows block scoping, so creating scope after case would be possible

Comment: Note that even though block-scoping now exists in JS, `case` still doesn't create its own scope by default. Using the `let` keyword in different consecutive `case`s, for example, would throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

> Is scope for the entire switch/case?

No, it's for the entire containing function, or global scope if you're outside a function.

(There are a obscure few cases in which JavaScript introduces extra scope, but that's about it.)

> Warning: 'i' is already defined

I don't really agree with this being a warning. I would prefer to leave the code as it is, with the blocks' independent uses of the variable `i`.

What it wants you to do is remove the `var` from all but the first declaration, or maybe add `var i` before the switch and remove `var` from all the `for`​s. But now those blocks don't stand alone, and a quick cut-and-paste (for, say, refactoring the `switch` into separate `function`​s) leaves you with loops referencing an `i` that hasn't been declared `var`. This is an accidental global, and it's a horrible JS trap which can be a real pain to debug.

JSLint makes the same complaint. I would typically ignore it. It does no harm to declare a variable `var` twice in one block.

Comment: Yes I know it works. I just do not like to have warnings in production code. But a talk here in the office about it revealed that jQuery does the same thing. So I may leave it. Thank you for the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if javascript had block scope, there is the fall-through feature which kinda disqualifies the notion of having a scope per `case`...