# Why is a switch statement only one underlying block?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, let

I am glad JavaScript has the new [let statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to declare a block scope local variable. However, there appears to be a type error when declaring to `let` variables in a switch statement, which would be a very useful scenario to use `let`.

```
function test(x) { 
  'use strict';
  switch (x) {
    case 0:
      let foo;
      break;

    case 1:
      let foo; // TypeError for redeclaration.
      break;
  }
}
```

Sure enough, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone_and_errors_with_let) shows this example:

> You may encounter errors in switch statements because there is only one underlying block.

So why is a switch statement only one underlying block?

Comment: You can't have 2 `foo`'s in the same block.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I'm not sure you read my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524397/what-is-the-javascript-variable-scope-in-a-switch-case-statment

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block): _A block statement ... is used to group zero or more statements. **The block is delimited by a pair of curly brackets.**_

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the similar question. It's not quite the same since it was asked before `let` and the answer says "Javascript does not use block scope." which is not true.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks. It looks like mcfedr answered with an example using curly brackets that works well.

Comment: Also relevant for [C# switch scope](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3652408/266535). Looks like the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically comes down to down to how switches work, and its expressed in the syntax that it has only one pair of `{}`

Because of how you can fall though from one case to the other by missing out `break` - in that case you would want to have the same scope.

You can put an extra `{}` around you case:

```
switch(a) {
    case 1:{
        let a = 1;
    }
}
```

This is the case is most c-ish languages with block scope.